# Fedora broke after update

Tags: fedora, dnf

TLDR: Is there a way to check which packages are broken and reinstall them? Or maybe reinstall all the packages in the system in general? I am using fedora 38.

I updated a bounch of packages on my OS last night, nothing special, just a small update. This morning I noticed that everything related to media on the computer does not work - videos are not played either in the browser, not from files, audio devices are not available and the video driver periodically gives errors in the logs.
I started reinstalling the video related packages, and in the process got a bunch of errors  "*some package* is empty not checked". I'm trying to reinstall those packages as well, but I'm getting more and more errors.

Update:
sudo dnf reinstall $(rpm -qa) gives me a bunch of errors like: Installed package [package name] (from updates) is not available.

Comment: `some package is empty not checked` `Installed package [package name] (from updates) is not available` - is fedora really that vague, no wonder you can't fix it if it just tells you *some package* and *package name*

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, I get the same error about 100 times on different packages, that's why I just wrote the package name

Comment: yeah, I get that ... you can see the borken packages, we can't, so, you have a better chance of fixing your issue :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I actually fixed it. Package names won't help here. there are just random broken packages. Now I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple

Run: sudo dnf reinstall '*'

Get a lot of errors due to the fact that many packages have both the old and the new version installed

Remove all old versions of the packages by the names that you received in the previous step

Run: sudo dnf reinstall '*'

Waiting (enough)

Everything is working (for me)